# run 'watch' before serve- node ionic2

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic2

I am working with ionic 2. And I don't know why when I'm trying to run 'ionic serve', it answer with the next messeges:

WARN: ionic.config.js has been deprecated, you can remove it. 
WARN: No 'serve:before' gulp task found! 
Your gulpfile contains a 'watch' task already! Add:

```
gulp.task('serve:before', ['watch']);
```

to your gulpfile to have Ionic CLI run 'watch' before serve.

WARN: ionic.config.js has been deprecated, you can remove it.

In the gulpfile.js I add that line and it works, but when I change some html file it don't update. I have to stop serve. And run the command again.
PD: I have alredy install all dependencies with npm install
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recently Ionic updated their CLI tool (to beta.21). They have obviously made some changes in the gulp file which is being generated by their newly updated CLI. The project you are trying to run was created using an older version of CLI (probably beta.19). That's why you are getting that warning. Regarding the 'ionic.config.js has been deprecated' line, that file is simply a checkpoint to see whether you are using the latest version of Ionic CLI.

There is a quick fix (which I did).

1) Create a new ionic app (possibly using the same template as the one you are trying to run i.e., blank or sidemenu or tabs).

2) Copy the contents of the app directory of the project which you are trying to run to the app directory of the newly generated project.

(I don't know whether this is the right method, but this will work.)

Hope this helps you. Thanks.